# Can I fake my internet connection type?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

I am trying to apply to work from home jobs but they all require wired internet (I had to give them my router number and provider company). Some websites specifically list "no wireless internet allowed"...but that is all we have available in my town. I've called several providers and they all say there are no more connections available. Not only that, but it would cost thousands of dollars to set up a new connection, and I don't have that kind of $.

So can I fake my connection? I know they sell converters (it makes your connection appear "wired"...if that's what that means anyway.

I am not tech savy or anything like that. I just need a job.

Comment: Lots of questions here. 1. what do they mean by "wireless internet" - do they mean public wifi hotspots? 2. can they detect that type of connection? 3. can you provide an example of a "converter"?

Comment: Depending on the above, you could get a wired wireless device that you connect to over a wire, but it connects over wifi to your ISP. But what will work will depend entirely on the company and how they enforce this.

Comment: 1.non-wired internet connections.  Not wifi spots...For example, I had to give them my router number and provider company.

Comment: Then they will simply check with the provider company... no device or converter will work

Comment: I'm confused. When you obtained your home Internet connection, did the installation involve connecting a box _router_ to a cable, or fiber? I get that you probably use wireless for all your devices, but isn't your ISP connection wired?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution migth be a Network Bridge
How to for win10:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-a-network-bridge-windows

Answer (score 0):

I use an old cell phone and easytether,www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android.html.
I work from home and my ethernet port went out. It installs easytether network adapter and uses the wifi from your router passing through the cell phones wifi connection. I have fast wifi and a recent used cell phone. It then makes the wifi Icon and wireless network adapter appear as though it's a wired connection. I have passed numerous @home tests where they have you download and run a scan and then uploads it to the techs. Works everytime. It even makes the tray icon change in case I get remote takeovers for tech support.